# WC Subscriptions: Ability to upgrade listings created from package subscriptions

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I have WooCommece installed with WC Subscriptions and WP paid listings.
My site offers products of type package subscriptions. At the moment I have three types of products: free, premium and featured.

What I want to do is to add upgrade package functionality. For instance, you have free package subscription and you have created one listing.

What customer wants is to be able to upgrade his free listing. For instance, to have one option: "Upgrade listing to featured", and you just need to pay additional fee and your listing will be upgraded to the "Featured" type.

Is there is a way do to this ?

Thanks